# How do I create a ggplot bubble plot with multiple shapes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hello and thanks in advance,

I would like to have four distinct shapes in my bubble plot to represent the different ponds on the x-axis (RHM1 and RHM2 are replicates of the same pond so they should be the same shape).  I figured this should be straightforward, yet here I am, hours later!  My code is below, and I do not understand why `aes(shape = taxclass)` isn't being applied.

```
p2 <- ggplot(data_melt, aes(x=pond, y=variable, group = pond)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = taxclass, fill = pond, size = value), alpha = 0.75, shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.box = "horizontal", legend.direction = "horizontal",
        panel.background = element_blank()) +
  xlab("Pond") +
  ylab("Taxonomy") +
  theme_linedraw(base_size = 18) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text( size = 15, face = "bold")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1/1)

print(p2)
```

I know I haven't specified any specific shape, could that be the problem?

Thank you!!

Here is my df for reproducibility (it's pretty long):

```
> dput(data_melt)
structure(list(pond = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("RHM1", 
"RHM2", "Lilly", "TS", "SS"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L), .Label = c("Bacteroidetes.vadinHA17", "Geobacter", "Methanolobus", 
"Syntrophus", "Anaeromyxobacter", "Endozoicomonas", "Anaerolineaceae", 
"Bacteroidales", "Coriobacteriia"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.0154239119756361, 
0, 0.000294724432655467, 0, 0.000491207387759112, 0, 0.0600255427841635, 
0.00117889773062187, 0.098437960506926, 0.000196482955103645, 
0.110226937813145, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000491207387759112, 0.00137538068572551, 
0, 0, 0.000196482955103645, 0.00422438353472836, 0.00363493466941743, 
0.00864525002456037, 0.000196482955103645, 0.0829158070537381, 
9.82414775518224e-05, 0.000294724432655467, 0.0286865114451321, 
0.0644464092739955, 0.0347774830533451, 0.0421455938697318, 0.00275076137145103, 
0.14716573337263, 0.120345810000982, 0.00108065625307005, 0.000687690342862757, 
0.0882208468415365, 0.0609097160821299, 0.00854700854700855, 
0.000687690342862757, 0.00147362216327734, 0, 0.000491207387759112, 
0.000785931820414579, 0, 0.000491207387759112, 0.00530503978779841, 
0, 0.0026525198938992, 0, 0.05, 0.0322727272727273, 0.0490909090909091, 
0.0277272727272727, 0.00318181818181818, 0.0372727272727273, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0477272727272727, 0.105454545454545, 0.0690909090909091, 
0.0504545454545455, 0.0345454545454545, 0.000909090909090909, 
0.0695454545454545, 0, 0, 0.0413636363636364, 0.00863636363636364, 
0.02, 0, 0.0140909090909091, 0, 0, 0, 0.0181818181818182, 0, 
0.00727272727272727, 0.00954545454545455, 0.005, 0.0522727272727273, 
0.0240909090909091, 0.0168181818181818, 0.0245454545454545, 0, 
0.0136363636363636, 0.0254545454545455, 0, 0, 0.106818181818182, 
0, 0, 0.00681818181818182, 0.0118181818181818, 0, 0, 0, 0.0163636363636364, 
0, 0.0255695025569503, 0.0669456066945607, 0.0116225011622501, 
0.0450953045095304, 0.00650860065086007, 0.0497443049744305, 
0.00418410041841004, 0, 0, 0.0701999070199907, 0.124128312412831, 
0.158066015806602, 0.0734542073454207, 0.0613668061366806, 0, 
0.0832171083217108, 0, 0, 0.0469549046954905, 0, 0.00697350069735007, 
0, 0.0153417015341702, 0, 0, 0, 0.0283589028358903, 0, 0.0292887029288703, 
0.0344026034402603, 0, 0.0204556020455602, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.00836820083682008, 0, 0, 0, 0.0148768014876801, 0, 0, 
0.0148768014876801, 0, 0.00639163277164439, 0.0755374782103428, 
0.100522951772225, 0.296920395119117, 0.0180127832655433, 0, 
0.0133643230679837, 0.00290528762347472, 0, 0, 0, 0.0174317257408483, 
0.0273097036606624, 0.00464846019755956, 0.0331202789076119, 
0, 0.0226612434631028, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0052295177222545, 0, 0, 
0.0203370133643231, 0.0145264381173736, 0, 0.0976176641487507, 
0, 0.0598489250435793, 0.0244044160371877, 0.00813480534572923, 
0.0122022080185938, 0, 0.00406740267286461, 0.0273097036606624, 
0, 0.00581057524694945, 0, 0, 0, 0.0429982568274259, 0, 0, 0.00755374782103428, 
0.0238233585124927, 0, 0, 0.0122022080185938, 0.0151074956420686, 
0.0204081632653061, 0.0433673469387755, 0.0497448979591837, 0.0529336734693878, 
0.017219387755102, 0, 0.0255102040816327, 0.00701530612244898, 
0, 0, 0.0306122448979592, 0.0644132653061224, 0.0771683673469388, 
0.0191326530612245, 0.03125, 0, 0.0471938775510204, 0, 0, 0.024234693877551, 
0.00255102040816327, 0.0076530612244898, 0, 0.0159438775510204, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0331632653061225, 0, 0, 0.0165816326530612, 0, 0.0459183673469388, 
0.0197704081632653, 0.0235969387755102, 0.0427295918367347, 0, 
0.014030612244898, 0.0108418367346939, 0, 0, 0.160076530612245, 
0, 0, 0.0114795918367347, 0.0573979591836735, 0, 0, 0.0216836734693878, 
0.00637755102040816, 0.00374181478016838, 0.00374181478016838, 
0, 0.0177736202057998, 0, 0.0308699719363891, 0.0149672591206735, 
0.0523854069223573, 0, 0, 0.0159027128157156, 0.010289990645463, 
0.00935453695042095, 0, 0.00467726847521048, 0.0514499532273152, 
0.0299345182413471, 0.379794200187091, 0.0654817586529467, 0, 
0.0533208606173994, 0.0748362956033676, 0, 0, 0, 0.0112254443405051, 
0, 0.0177736202057998, 0, 0.00561272217025257, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.146866230121609, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0123180291153415, 0, 0, 0.0548712206047032, 0, 0, 
0, 0.0548712206047032, 0.174692049272116, 0.0739081746920493, 
0.0806270996640538, 0.0884658454647256, 0, 0.0772676371780515, 
0, 0, 0.154535274356103, 0, 0, 0, 0.0425531914893617, 0.0123180291153415, 
0, 0, 0.0940649496080627, 0, 0.0313549832026876, 0.0201567749160134, 
0.00559910414333707, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0223964165733483, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0190156599552573, 0.00671140939597315, 
0.0223713646532438, 0.0268456375838926, 0, 0.0357941834451902, 
0, 0, 0, 0.058165548098434, 0.177852348993289, 0.12751677852349, 
0.0917225950782998, 0.10178970917226, 0, 0.110738255033557, 0, 
0, 0.17337807606264, 0, 0, 0, 0.0302013422818792, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.0100671140939597, 0, 0, 0, 0.00782997762863535, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0423031727379553, 
0.063454759106933, 0.027027027027027, 0, 0.0376028202115159, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0305522914218566, 0.106933019976498, 0.0987074030552291, 
0.0552291421856639, 0.0387779083431257, 0, 0.045828437132785, 
0, 0, 0.0552291421856639, 0, 0.0152761457109283, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.0329024676850764, 0, 0.0305522914218566, 0.0481786133960047, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0587544065804935, 0, 0, 0.0399529964747356, 
0.0881316098707403, 0, 0, 0.0481786133960047, 0.036427732079906
), taxclass = c("Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", 
"Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", 
"Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", 
"Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", 
"Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", 
"Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", 
"Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", 
"Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", 
"Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", 
"Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", 
"Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", 
"Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", 
"Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Methanomicrobia", "Bacteroidia", 
"Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", 
"Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", 
"Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", 
"Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", 
"Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", 
"Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", 
"Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", 
"Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", 
"Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", 
"Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", 
"Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", 
"Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", 
"Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", 
"Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", 
"Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", 
"Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", 
"Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", 
"Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", 
"Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", 
"Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", 
"Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", 
"Anaerolineae", "Anaerolineae", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", 
"Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", 
"Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", 
"Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", 
"Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", 
"Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", 
"Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", 
"Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", 
"Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", 
"Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", 
"Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", 
"Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", 
"Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", 
"Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", 
"Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", 
"Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", 
"Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Deltaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Coriobacteriia", 
"Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", 
"Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", 
"Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", 
"Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", 
"Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", 
"Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", 
"Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", 
"Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", 
"Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", 
"Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", 
"Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", 
"Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", "Coriobacteriia", 
"Coriobacteriia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", 
"Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", 
"Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", 
"Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", 
"Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", 
"Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", 
"Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", 
"Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", 
"Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", 
"Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia", 
"Bacteroidia", "Bacteroidia")), row.names = c(NA, -450L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You have 2 `shape` one inside `aes` and another outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `geom_point` you override the mapping with the code that says `shape=21`.